# Object Parenting Line Appearing in Render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, parent

I'm rendering an animation and what appears to be the relationship line between the rig and its origin point (or maybe between the rig and the object its parented to) appear in the actual render. They follow the object (in this case the rat), around as it moves. I have no idea how this came about or how to fix it. I'm using EEVEE and I've checked all render settings so I don't know why it's showing up. The end of the relationship line just ends at an orange dot. There are no empties in this scene. Even when I am in rendered view, the line doesn't show up in the viewport - it only appears in the final render. [image: You can see the black line which almost looks like it's coming from the tail of the rat going to the edge of the sewer]

Comment: I can confirm that this line is between the armature and the rat itself. In Edit mode I can see this line, but I have no idea why it's showing up in the render.